# python pandas to csv file save, not override

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I read a `csv` file and did some modification of the data repeatedly. And I tried to save the csv with the file name "`naver_news_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM.csv`. However, If I run this program repeatedly, but I can find only last csv file with "`naver_news.csv`".

This is the code as followed.

```
df.to_csv("C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/news/naver_news.csv", date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index = False, sep=',', encoding='ms949')
```

Then I can only find one "`naver_news.csv`" file in my computer. 
The result file nave that I am expecting is as followed.

```
naver_news_2018_09_17_10_42.csv
naver_news_2018_09_17_11_42.csv
naver_news_2018_09_17_12_42.csv
naver_news_2018_09_17_13_42.csv
```

Please let me know to save csv file with current current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to insert the timestamp label into the filename yourself.

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M')
filename = f"C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/news/naver_news_{ts}.csv"
# filename = "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/news/naver_news_{}.csv".format(ts) 
df.to_csv(filename, index=False, encoding='ms949')
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I works well. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to get timestamp whenever you want,

```
from datetime import datetime


def get_date_time(fmt='%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'):
    date_stamp = datetime.now().strftime(fmt)
    print("%s " % date_stamp)
    return date_stamp


file_name = "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/news/naver_news_{}.csv".format(get_date_time())
print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation, `date_format` affects only the *Format string for datetime object*  inside the `dataframe`, not the filename, but you can use something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
fn = "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/news/naver_news_{}.csv".format(format(datetime.now(), '%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M'))
df.to_csv(fn, index = False, sep=',', encoding='ms949')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need to erase it. But do you have any idea to make the filename like "filenave_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM.csv"?